# Vaadin BrowserFrame with relative path

Tags: html, vaadin, vaadin7

I am trying to load an HTML file that references images in a sub-directory.  Here is the structure:
[image]
Basically, BrowserFrame cannot load the images under Overview_files.  It works fine if I load it directly from the desktop.

Here is a snippet of the HTML code:

```
<p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:0in;
margin-left:.75in;margin-bottom:.0001pt">
<span style="mso-no-proof:yes">
<!--[if gte vml 1]><v:shape
 id="_x0000_i1069" type="#_x0000_t75" style='width:1075.8pt;height:120pt;
 visibility:visible;mso-wrap-style:square'>
 <v:imagedata src="Overview_files/image003.png" o:title="" cropright="-6f"/>
</v:shape><![endif]--><!--[if !vml]-->
<img border="0" width="1434" height="160" src="Overview_files/image004.gif" v:shapes="_x0000_i1069">
<!--[endif]-->
</span>
</p>
```

And here is the Vaadin code I use:

```
helpDoc = new BrowserFrame();
docResource = new FileResource( docFile ); // docFile is full path to file on disk, as a File
helpDoc.setSource(docResource);
```

Should I be loading local HTML files in a different way?  I saw one older post (2015, so very outdated) where a guy implied he loaded it in a ZIP file, but he I am not sure how he did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Vaadin `BrowserFrame` is an abstraction over `<iframe>`.

[`FileResource`](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/application/application-resources/#application.resources.file) only loads the HTML file; it does not make the folder or any sub-resources available.

To get this to work, the HTML source (iframe `src`) should be served separately, for instance, from a static content folder that you configure in your server.

Comment: It is a static resource, since it is a static, non-dynamic file located outside of my application (somewhere on disk where my boss can update without needing developers).  You probably mean something different, though.  Anyway, does this mean it has to be done with an `ExternalResource` instead of a `FileResource`, thus using an URL instead of a file system path?  Can you be more specific about what you mean with "served separately"?  I assume you mean via a normal URL, but just confirming.

Comment: Correct. You will need to make the content accessible through a URL (ExternalResource). You can put them in a public folder that your server is already serving, or alternatively configure your server to serve them from where they are.